# How to get inside part of a selection (border) of an image

Tags: crop, photoshop

I had this question previously but it is not working anymore with Photoshop 2022 : https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55494/how-to-quickly-get-inside-of-this-magic-wand-tool-border-selection-complex-ima

I dont know why

So here a new question

Here an example image

[image]

I select its white border like this with magic wand

[image]

Now how do I get inside of this selection (check the image above). The selection is continuous

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the selection radius one pixel at a time or raise the selection radius, also reduce or raise feathering. All in the `Select` menu and then choose `Modify` (Modify is only available once the selection is made).